# Refreeze Ground Beef

Tags: ground-beef

I have a 10 pound log of ground beef - I want to thaw it and make meat-loafs, meatballs, and hamburger patties - once made refreeze for future use - is this appropriate?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. He's asking about rules for freezing cooked beef, not refreezing raw beef.

Comment: @Pdxd Duplicate means that the question is *answered* in the other question, not that they are phrased in identical manners.   This question is completely answered, and by marking at as a duplicate, we have one place to provide all of the answers on the topic, while providing a link to the OP and anyone who finds this question to where those answers are found.

Comment: I would think for searching purposes that one might like a more granular question, even if it's answered elsewhere. That's just me, though.

Comment: @Pdxd I wouldn't be so sure - I suspect the OP may in fact intend to refreeze raw. You'll certainly get better quality by freezing raw hamburger patties and cooking them later. In any case, SAJ14SAJ is right - duplicates aren't completely strict.

Comment: @MrBoJangles As SAJ14SAJ said, duplicates do leave behind a link, so they help with searching without needing to have the same answers repeated in multiple places.

Comment: Ok maybe I read the question wrong. I thought he meant cooked meat.

Comment: That makes sense.